# Joining a dataframe on 2 different columns gives error "column are ambiguous"

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, ambiguous

I have 2 dataframes:

- `df` contains all train routes with origin and arrival columns (both ids and names)
- `df_relation` contains Station (Gare) name, relation and API number.

Goal: I need to join these two dataframes twice on both origin and arrival columns.

I tried this:

```py
df.groupBy("origin", "origin_id", "arrival", "direction") \
    .agg({'time_travelled': 'avg'}) \
    .filter(df.direction == 0) \
    .join(df_relation, df.origin == df_relation.Gare, "inner") \
    .join(df_relation, df.arrival == df_relation.Gare, "inner") \
    .orderBy("Relation")
    .show()
```

But I got the following AnalysisException

> AnalysisException:  Column Gare#1708 are ambiguous.
> It's probably because you joined several Datasets together, and some of these Datasets are the same.
> This column points to one of the Datasets but Spark is unable to figure out which one.
> Please alias the Datasets with different names via `Dataset.as` before joining them, and specify the column using qualified name, e.g. `df.as("a").join(df.as("b"), $"a.id" > $"b.id")`.
> You can also set spark.sql.analyzer.failAmbiguousSelfJoin to false to disable this check.

How to rewrite this?

I have unsuccessfully tried to blindly follow the error recommendation like this

```py
.as("a").join(df_relation.as("b"), $"a.arrival" == $"b.Gare", "inner")
```

This is my first dataframe (`df`):

```
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+
|              origin| origin_id|             arrival|direction|avg(time_travelled)|
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+
|        Gare du Nord|IDFM:71410|La Plaine Stade d...|      1.0| 262.22222222222223|
|        Gare du Nord|IDFM:71410|Aéroport CDG 1 (T...|      1.0| 1587.7551020408164|
|Villeparisis - Mi...|IDFM:68916|       Mitry - Claye|      1.0|              240.0|
|          Villepinte|IDFM:73547|Parc des Expositions|      1.0|  90.33898305084746|
|     Le Blanc-Mesnil|IDFM:72648|    Aulnay-sous-Bois|      1.0| 105.04273504273505|
|Aéroport CDG 1 (T...|IDFM:73596|Aéroport Charles ...|      1.0| 145.27777777777777|
```

This my second dataframe (`df_relation`):

```
+-----------------------------------------+--------+--------+
|Gare                                     |Relation|Gare Api|
+-----------------------------------------+--------+--------+
|Aéroport Charles de Gaulle 2 (Terminal 2)|1       |87001479|
|Aéroport CDG 1 (Terminal 3) - RER        |2       |87271460|
|Parc des Expositions                     |3       |87271486|
|Villepinte                               |4       |87271452|
```

And this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------+-----------+
|              origin|  origin_id|             arrival|direction|avg(time_travelled)|Relation|Api origin|Api arrival|
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------+-----------+
|Aéroport Charles ...| IDFM:73699|Aéroport CDG 1 (T...|      0.0| 110.09345794392523|       1|  87001479|   87271460|
|Aéroport CDG 1 (T...| IDFM:73596|Parc des Expositions|      0.0| 280.17543859649123|       2|  87271460|   87271486|
|Aéroport CDG 1 (T...| IDFM:73596|        Gare du Nord|      0.0|             1707.4|       2|  87271460|   87271007|
|Parc des Expositions| IDFM:73568|          Villepinte|      0.0|  90.17543859649123|       3|  87271486|   87271452|
|          Villepinte| IDFM:73547|   Sevran Beaudottes|      0.0| 112.45614035087719|       4|  87271452|   87271445|
|   Sevran Beaudottes| IDFM:73491|    Aulnay-sous-Bois|      0.0| 168.24561403508773|       5|  87271445|   87271411|
|       Mitry - Claye| IDFM:69065|Villeparisis - Mi...|      0.0| 210.51724137931035|       6|  87271528|   87271510|
|Villeparisis - Mi...| IDFM:68916|         Vert Galant|      0.0|              150.0|       7|  87271510|   87271510|
```

Comment: the column names will clash because you're joining the same df twice. one hack is to rename the columns in the while joining. `df.join(df2.select([func.col(k).alias(k+'_origin) for k in df2.columns]).alias('df2_origin'), df.origin == func.col('df2_origin.gare_origin'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take the original `df` and join `df_relation` *twice*. This way you create duplicate columns for every column in `df_relation`. Column "Gare" just happens to be the first of them, so it is depicted in the error message.

To avoid the error, you will have to create `alias` for your dataframes. Notice how I create them
`df_agg.alias("agg")`
`df_relation.alias("rel_o")`
`df_relation.alias("rel_a")`
and how I latter reference them before every column.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df_agg = (
    df.filter(F.col("direction") == 0)
    .groupBy("origin", "origin_id", "arrival", "direction")
    .agg({"time_travelled": "avg"})
)
df_result = (
    df_agg.alias("agg")
    .join(df_relation.alias("rel_o"), F.col("agg.origin") == F.col("rel_o.Gare"), "inner")
    .join(df_relation.alias("rel_a"), F.col("agg.arrival") == F.col("rel_a.Gare"), "inner")
    .orderBy("rel_o.Relation")
    .select(
        "agg.*",
        "rel_o.Relation",
        F.col("rel_o.Gare Api").alias("Api origin"),
        F.col("rel_a.Gare Api").alias("Api arrival"),
    )
)
```